# Java Swing JComboBox uneditable when JTextField entered

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I've come across a very weird problem. I had a JPanel which contains JTextFields and JComboBoxes. I can change the JComboBox's when the JPanel loads but as soon as I touch or edit one of the JTextFields it doesn't let me change the JComboBox...

Here is all of the ServerPanel.java code: http://pastebin.com/W0LhreMF

It is quite long so I have pasted it to pastebin so it can be read more easily.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable JFrame with JPanel and one JTextField together with JComboBox

Comment: what version of Java?